# Query that finds most common genre

Tags: ms-access

Given database of the website "eMovies" that manage data about cinema movies.

> Write in SQL query that finds most common genre (with the biggest number of movies)

The tables:

[image]

**My attempt:**:

```
  SELECT MAX(moviecount), Genres.GenreDescr
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(GenresMovies.GenreID) as  moviecount ,Genres.GenreDescr
  FROM GenresMovies , Genres 
  WHERE GenresMovies.GenreID = Genres.GenreID
  GROUP BY GenresMovies.GenreID, Genres .GenreDescr )
```

My code does not work, and I'm stuck.